# SQL, oracle and making views

Tags: sql, oracle, view

How do I make views in Oracle and could someone please explain views?

Comment: Use the [`CREATE VIEW` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html).

Answer (score 0):

To cut a long story short, your problem is how to make data available only to those people who are allowed to view it. Have a look at [Virtual private database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#DBSEG007) as it

> adds a dynamic WHERE clause to a SQL statement that is issued against
>   the table, view, or synonym to which an Oracle Virtual Private
>   Database security policy was applied.

`SYS_CONTEXT` is something you'll be using frequently, if you choose to take this path.